# UIL loading exact image

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I have another issue with Universal Image loader. Trying to use it in a listview and gridview for displaying large amount of images. The urls passed to UIL contain high res images. I have tried using almost all scaletypes, and it still loads images much slower on mobile network than Original LazyList. As I understand it first loads the exact image and then resizes it. Is there a way to download smaller amount of data to display this very much scaled image. Also it sometimes craches while loading images with two different exceptions. EOFException, and SocketTimeoutException. Any ideas what I am doing wrong here ?

**Update:**
Adapter class:

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    
    private Activity activity;
    private List<String[]> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoade1r imageLoader; 
    public boolean show;
    public final String webs = "http://www";
    public DisplayImageOptions options;
    public ImageLoader nostra;
    public LazyAdapter(Activity a, List<String[]> d, boolean flag) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        show=flag;

        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(a.getApplicationContext())
        .enableLogging()
        .build();

        nostra = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        nostra.init(config);

        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .cacheOnDisc()
        .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.failed)
        .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
        .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
        .build();

        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader=new ImageLoade1r(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        
        String[] url = data.get(position);
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);

        TextView text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text);;
        ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
        ProgressBar spinner = (ProgressBar) vi.findViewById(R.id.prgrsItem);
        RelativeLayout layo = (RelativeLayout) vi.findViewById(R.id.thelayout);
        if(url[1].trim().equals("folder"))
        {
         String img = webs+url[3].trim() + url[2] +"title"+".jpg";
         display(image, img, spinner);
         text.setText(url[2].replaceAll("_", " "));
        }
        else
        {
         String img;
         if(show==true)
          img = webs+url[3] + url[2]+"title"+".jpg";
         else
          img = webs+url[0];
         display(image, img, spinner);
         text.setText(url[2].replaceAll("_", " "));
        }
        if(show==true)
        {
         text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else
        {
         text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        return vi;
    }
    public void display(ImageView img, String url, final ProgressBar spinner)
    {
        nostra.displayImage(url, img, options, new ImageLoadingListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
             spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            @Override
            public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
             spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             EasyTracker.getTracker().sendException(failReason.toString(), false);
            }
            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
             spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            @Override
            public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {
                
            }
    });
    }
}
```

**Update** EOFException:

```
03-21 13:51:55.800: E/ImageLoader(31605): null
03-21 13:51:55.800: E/ImageLoader(31605): java.io.EOFException
03-21 13:51:55.800: E/ImageLoader(31605):  at libcore.io.Streams.readAsciiLine(Streams.java:203)
03-21 13:51:55.800: E/ImageLoader(31605):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponseHeaders(HttpEngine.java:544)
03-21 13:51:55.800: E/ImageLoader(31605):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:784)
03-21 13:51:55.800: E/ImageLoader(31605):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:274)
03-21 13:51:55.800: E/ImageLoader(31605):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:479)
03-21 13:51:55.800: E/ImageLoader(31605):  at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromNetwork(BaseImageDownloader.java:113)
03-21 13:51:55.800: E/ImageLoader(31605):  at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStream(BaseImageDownloader.java:84)
03-21 13:51:55.800: E/ImageLoader(31605):  at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.saveImageOnDisc(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:299)
03-21 13:51:55.800: E/ImageLoader(31605):  at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryLoadBitmap(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:237)
03-21 13:51:55.800: E/ImageLoader(31605):  at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.run(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:149)
03-21 13:51:55.800: E/ImageLoader(31605):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
03-21 13:51:55.800: E/ImageLoader(31605):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
03-21 13:51:55.800: E/ImageLoader(31605):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder() 
    .cacheOnDisc() 
    .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY) 
    .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
    .build();.try this

Comment: are you caching in memory or disc??. can u post some relevant codes.

Comment: My build is exactly like you wrote.

Comment: post some relevant code.

Comment: Like which part? The problems arise while using slow mobile internet. On wifi it works without problem

Comment: post your adapter code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26628/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-datenshi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use should use a view holder for performance.

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Your code might call findViewById() frequently during the scrolling of ListView, which can slow down performance. Even when the Adapter returns an inflated view for recycling, you still need to look up the elements and update them. A way around repeated use of findViewById() is to use the "view holder" design pattern.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70. The topic is abot listview and view holder.

SokectTimeOut Exception is thrown when a timeout expired on a socket read or accept operation.

```
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(a.getApplicationContext())
    .enableLogging()
    .build();
    .imageDownloader(new URLConnectionImageDownloader(5 * 1000, 20 * 1000)) // connectTimeout (5 s), readTimeout (20 s)
```

For EOFException check the link.

http://code.google.com/p/libs-for-android/issues/detail?id=14.

```
  System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false").
```

Issue similar was raised and some suggested to try the above before opening HTTP url connection.

Probably has nothing to do with your code.

Comment: First thank you for your help and time. My ListView is no more that 12 elements, so I guess findViewById isn't any problem here. But thanks for the tip! As for SocketTimeOut Exception you were right, changing timeout got rid of it. The last one is EOF Exception which is thrown only at sometimes.. Any idea why?

Comment: looks like it has something to do with image downloading.

Comment: Ok, I'll wait a little bit before accepting answer, maybe somebody else would know why this crash sometimes occurs. Thank you for your help once again

Comment: check the last link in the answer.

Comment: Can you explain fetch urls? I'm not native speaker so.. So basically from your given link I can say that it is my 4.0.4 android bug, not anything in my app.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26639/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-datenshi)

Comment: can u test your app on android ics and below and check if you get the exception.