# Loading big images with least effort

Tags: android, listview, optimization

I have high quality, rich in color images in my server. I am displaying them in `ListView` in small ImageViews. After the user selects item, he gets fullscreen of the selected image. In this way after selecting image, the image loads quickly, as it was already loaded and I save them in cache.

The problem is that the whole List on first startup is loading pretty slow, as each item needs to be downloaded. Is there any way I could reduce the image loading in `ListView`? In my vision the `ListView` should load pretty quick, and after selection the image may load longer. I know I could optimize this by passing low quality, resized images from server to list. And after selection pass high quality image url. But this is a very big job, as I have ton of images and resizing each one of them would be a pain.

Any ideas how could I optimize this even a little?

**Update**: I guess my question wasn't clear enough. There is no problem with ListView, or image loading. I do not hung user at some "loading" screen, I do asynchrounsly load images, and I do simbolize that images are being loaded for each item in ListView. But with slow internet connection, the thumbnails just stay there for too long, I think the user would just quit the app... I'm looking for a way to optimize loading process. Loading just resized Images would be great, something like: 50kb for ListView and fullsize for SelectedView. I think in such way the user experience would be much better.

Comment: The process which you are doing is correct, and the thing which you are thinking about to do (resize) is possible through some code. And yes High speed net connection is required to load images quickly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15543811/uil-loading-exact-image. You asked the question. has it got anything to do with the question in the link??

Comment: Resizing through code would be great. But I do not even have a clue, what should I begin looking at. Raghunandan, no, I got it working, just looking for a way to optimize it now. Sorry for forgeting to accept your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader. Universal Image Loader is Asynchronous, uses caching and is a improves version of LazyLoading.

You can cache images in memory or disc. You can also provide custom folder to cache images. Universal Image Loader also provides you with other configuration options.

https://github.com/thest1/LazyList. you can also use lazy loading.

For performance and smooth scrolling use ViewHolder.http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70. The talk on View Holder for listview.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [universal image loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader). It enables you to download the images on a background thread. Basically you display the `ListView` with some default thumbnail and when each image is downloaded the UIL replaces the thumbnail with the real image.

That way the user will not be trapped while the images are downloading, but showing all the thumbnails will surely require downloading all the big images until you start serving small variants for the images.